# Angular 2 Video player with hidden or encrypted video URL

Tags: javascript, html, angular, video, encryption

I want to integrate video player in angular 2, which hide or encrypted the video URL for no one can copy or download video.
I have implemented Videogular and Html5 video player but both of these aren't able to hide or encrypt video URL.
Here is my code,
Html :

```
<video id="videoDisplay" (click)="videoService.playVideo()" width="100%" height="100%"  class="embed-responsive-item"></video>
```

component:

```
playVideo() {
  if(this.videoElement.paused) {
    this.videoElement.play();
    this.isPlaying = true;
  } else {
    this.videoElement.pause();
    this.isPlaying = false;
  }
};
```

In inspect element I can able to see

```
<video _ngcontent-mrg-42="" class="embed-responsive-item" height="100%" id="videoDisplay" width="100%" src="http://**player.com/**/2**98856121208796647.hd.mp4?**=*asda9a516f7edca6c2f7csdasd40435ee02f275bbb6eea605"></video>
```

How can I hide this src from inspect element in angular 2

Comment: _"which hide or encrypted the video URL for no one can copy or download video"_ That is pointless, because the decrypted URL will always be available at some point.

Comment: @zeroflagL at some extent we can hide it. Many video stream site having this. So it is not impossible

Comment: you can't hide the source because javascript has to find it to open the video. if the value of your content is high enough that it's worth protecting you could implement a commercial DRM solution (eg use a player from Ooyala or BuyDRM) or create your own solution using Encrypted Media Extensions

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thanks. :)

Comment: If you are worried about scrappers then you break down your videos into smaller pieces. This is known as chunking and it takes the video and splits it into usable ranges and sends them over to the client. This article talks more about how you can implement such a thing. Encrypted Media Exchange https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/